# Postgres dblink

Tags: database, postgresql-9.3

I want to call a function of DB1 from a function which is in DB2.

I am using below code for the same :

```
PERFORM * FROM dblink('dbname=testDB
port=5432 user=postgres password=test', 'SELECT * FROM
fn_insert_data('|| REC_subscription.id ||', '|| REC_subscription.code ||','|| REC_subscription.start_date ||'
            ,'|| REC_subscription.end_date ||')');
```

But I am getting below error while executing function of DB2 :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PERFORM"
LINE 9:      PERFORM * FROM dblink('dbname=testDB
             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "PERFORM"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 237
```

Comment: `perform` can only be used inside a PL/pgSQL function. It's not a regular SQL statement. You need to use `SELECT`.

Comment: I am using the above code snippet in PL/pgSQL function only. But still it shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:
I used below command to for installing and registering dblink

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

and then i executed below command to check for the connect:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('myconn'
       ,'hostaddr=1.1.1.1 dbname=test user=postgres password=admin')
```